# Trying to send an mp3 file with IFTTT to Telegram - Invalid Bots API response

Tags: if-this-then-that, telegram

I'm trying to use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) web hooks to send an mp3 file to [Telegram](https://ifttt.com/telegram), but keep getting this error on almost every link I try.

This is the error in IFTTT's activity page:

> Telegram error: Invalid Bots API response

[image]

Examples:

- [A working link](http://media.blubrry.com/hastartupistiot/dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s1xqa5q8chugscf/Hastartupistiot_intro.mp3)
- [Not working link](http://media.blubrry.com/hastartupistiot/dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r47ncqr7wiwup84/hastartupistiot_orit.pod.mp3)

Any idea why it keeps failing?

I'm trying for sometime now, but no progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it after digging in Telegram's [bots api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) - **File size limit**.

There's a limit of 20 MB for files sent with an HTTP URL, and 50 MB if sent with `multipart/form-data` when uploaded from the browser.

The file that was working was 12 MB, while the other was 54 MB

[Quoting](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

> **Sending files**
>
> ...
>
> 2. Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
> 3. Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.