# What are the storage limits for Telegram's groups?

Tags: online-storage, telegram

We can read that:

> Since Telegram's launch in 2013, you can send files up to 1.5 GB and access them from any of your devices, including computers. Source: [Shared Files and Fast Mute](https://telegram.org/blog/shared-files).

Although it doesn't say anything about the groups.

So my question is, what is the storage limit for the group I've created?

Is it still 1.5GB per person (sent files), or there is some other limit per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's 1.5GB per person per file, regardless of the chat type.

---

Maybe the sentence you quoted wasn't clear enough:

> you can send files up to 1.5 GB

- Generally, you can send in Telegram

AND

> access them from any of your devices

- i.e. not only from the device you sent them

---

**Another way of writing this, that maybe would've been more clear to you about that, is:**

Since Telegram's launch in 2013, you can:

- Send files up to **1.5 GB**
- Access your files from any of your devices, including computers.

Why/what is it good for? Because it's perfect for everything from studying to sharing personal archives.

Comment: To clarify, in case of bots which I created, do they share the same quota with the main account?

Comment: There's no general quota, only limits on each file - bots have their own limitations regards the file sizes they can handle. Check out [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115125/177684)

Comment: Update July 2020: The size limit of one file increased to 2GB. Formal announce: [Profile Videos, 2 GB File Sharing, Group Stats, Improved People Nearby and More](https://telegram.org/blog/profile-videos-people-nearby-and-more)